# How to insert a number of column next to the post?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, code

I think the question I'm going to do is very simple, but I had to do here because I researched about it all day and found nothing.
Question: How is the code to make the graph below?
[image]

[image]
I can not enter the "black dots", without having to remove the column numbers. It looks like it is. (Fig 7)

Look at my code:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
   \node (a) at (0,0) {$$};
  \node (b) at (2,2) {$$}; 
  \node (c) at (-2,2) {$$};
  \node (d) at (0,4) {$$};
  \node (e) at (0,8) {$$};
  \node (f) at (2,6) {$$};
  \node (g) at (-2,6) {$$};
  \node (h) at (4,4) {$$};
  \node (i) at (-4,4) {$$};
  \node (j) at (-5,0) {$0$};
  \node (j) at (-5,2) {$1$};
  \node (j) at (-5,4) {$2$};
  \node (j) at (-5,6) {$3$};
  \node (j) at (-5,8) {$4$};


     \draw (a)--(b)--(h)--(f)--(e)--(g)--(i)--(c)--(a);
     \draw (c)--(d)--(f);
     \draw (i)--(b)--(d);    

  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4] \node (a) at (0,0) {$\bullet$}; \node (b) at (2,2) {$\bullet$}; \node (c) at (-2,2) {$\bullet$}; \node (d) at (0,4) {$\bullet$}; \node (e) at (0,8) {$\bullet$}; \node (f) at (2,6) {$\bullet$}; \node (g) at (-2,6) {$\bullet$}; \node (h) at (4,4) {$\bullet$}; \node (i) at (-4,4) {$\bullet$}; \node (j) at (-5,0) {$0$}; \node (j) at (-5,2) {$1$}; \node (j) at (-5,4) {$2$}; \node (j) at (-5,6) {$3$}; \node (j) at (-5,8) {$4$};

 \draw (a)--(b)--(h)--(f)--(e)--(g)--(i)--(c)--(a);
 \draw (c)--(d)--(f);
 \draw (i)--(b)--(d);    

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]